# How to implement custom diagram Project for VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How to implement custom diagram Project for VS2010?

Where can I find the exmaple?

---

It is no diagram designer project (Class Diagram Project/Sequence diagram project) example in the Visual Studio Integration Samples.

---

[image]

I hope can implement custom diagram elements in VS.NET Toolbok window,and custom diagram designer (like edmx diagram designer and sequence diagram designer).

Comment: can you expalin what you mean by a custom diagram project?

Comment: The Friday evening answer is: in a forest, toppled over.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Visual Studio SDK Integration Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166252%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). Specifically do any of the Editor or SDM samples give you information in the area in which you are looking.

Comment: But it is no diagram designer project (Class Diagram Project/Sequence diagram project) example in the Visual Studio Integration Samples.